# How to return the first node containing the item with maximum value in C linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, max, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am trying to return the first node that contains the item which has a maximum value. Here is my code,

```
struct ListNode* CreateNode(int item) {
    struct ListNode* Newnode = (struct 
    ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode)); //allocate new node
    Newnode->item = item; 
    Newnode->next = NULL; 
   return Newnode;}


struct ListNode* searchmaxvalNode (struct ListNode *head) {
      struct ListNode *cur = head;    
      int max = head->item;
      while(cur != NULL){
          if((cur->item) < max){
              max = cur->item;
           }
           cur = cur->next;
           return cur;
       }
       return NULL;
     }

struct ListNode { //list.h file
   int item;
struct ListNode *next;
  };
```

what is wrong with my searchmaxvalnode function?

Comment: It always returns the second node, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

For starters in general the pointer `head` can be equal to NULL. So your function can invoke undefined behavior because it will try to access memory using a null pointer.

Also this if statement

```
      if((cur->item) < max){
          max = cur->item;
       }
```

is incorrect and does not make a sense. In fact it selects a minimum value.

Also this return statement

```
       return cur;
```

at least shall be placed outside the while loop though it also does not make a sense because it returns a pointer to a current node instead of the returning a pointer to the node with the maximum value.

The function can look the following way.

```
struct ListNode * searchmaxvalNode ( struct ListNode *head ) 
{
    struct ListNode *max = head;

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( head = head->next ) != NULL )
        {
            if ( max->item < head->item ) max = head;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct ListNode 
{
    int item;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

struct ListNode * CreateNode( int item ) 
{
    struct ListNode *Newnode = malloc( sizeof( struct ListNode ) );
    
    if ( Newnode != NULL )
    {
        Newnode->item = item; 
        Newnode->next = NULL; 
    }
    
    return Newnode;
}

int push_front( struct ListNode **head, int item )
{
    struct ListNode *Newnode = CreateNode( item );
    int success = Newnode != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        Newnode->next = *head;
        *head = Newnode;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const struct ListNode *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->item );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

struct ListNode * searchmaxvalNode( struct ListNode *head ) 
{
    struct ListNode *max = head;

    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( head = head->next ) != NULL )
        {
            if ( max->item < head->item ) max = head;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct ListNode *head = NULL;
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
    
    const int N = 10;
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, rand() % N );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    struct ListNode *max = searchmaxvalNode( head );
    
    printf( "The maximum value stored in the list is %d\n", max->item );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 8 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 4 -> 5 -> 8 -> 4 -> null
The maximum value stored in the list is 8
```